# Shapefile or GeoJSON of all Caribbean Islands

Tags: data-request, geospatial, openstreetmap, north-america, south-america

I'm looking for a large-scale geospatial data set (or several components that could be merged) that includes all the islands of the Caribbean region. The trick is that as many of the physical individual islands as possible need to be listed individual features in the data table. In other words, I want the data set up so that it is easy to select particular islands (not countries) and style them individually.

I've tried Open Street Map -- specifically Quick OSM and the Overpass API, using the place:island tag. That works pretty well, but there are a not-insignificant number of islands missing (e.g. most of the bigger Florida Keys, the main island of Cuba (though the smaller islands of Cuba are included), some of the main islands of the Bahamas, and others).

Natural Earth has two problems -- the scale is not small enough, and the each table row represents a country (group of islands, or mainland and islands together), rather than an individual island.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [OSMData Land Polygons](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons) include all land areas in the world, which should mean it includes the data you are looking for. It's derived from `natural:coastline` rather than `place:island`, so it shouldn't have the same gaps for larger islands but may be excessively large and unwieldy. You may be able to pare it down or recreate it on a regional basis based on the description provided on the same page.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answers your question sufficiently feel free to mark it as such -- if there's more info I (or someone else) can provide you can ask for clarification in comments to help refine our answers. And welcome to Opendata.stackexchange :)

Comment: Thanks, @DGinzberg. I downloaded the Land Polygons, and the combined-polygons set works pretty well for my purposes. My only regret is that there are no island names in the attribute table, even for the big ones, but even so, this is way ahead of any other other polygon dataset.